# jQuery div flickers when added to document with slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flicker

When I add dynamically a div to another parent div (as in http://jsfiddle.net/RP3Zy/1/) all the parent div is rerendered, making it flickers. How can I avoid this?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <button id="hide">Hide all</button>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#add").click(function() {
        var divs = $(".dyn");
        console.log(divs.length);
        var adiv = $(".container").append('<div id="div" class="dyn">I\'m no more hidden!</div>').not(divs).hide().slideDown();
    });

    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $(".container").slideUp();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, when you're adding, you also `.hide().slideDown();` which I believe is making the flickering you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to slideDown against the whole parent element, when you really only want to slideDown on the one you're adding.  Something like this might seems to work:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
     elem = $('<div id="div" class="dyn">I\'m no more hidden!</div>').hide();

     $(".container").append(elem);

     elem.slideDown();
});

$("#hide").click(function() {
     $(".container").slideUp();
});
```

Check out an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RP3Zy/2/